# Generating pdf report from Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, report, r-markdown

What Is the best option to generate pdf reports from shiny app outputs ?
Currently I'm using rmarkdown, It is working very good when I'm using my local PC, but I can not download the report when I put the app on server !!!

Is there any alternative available ?

Comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html